# Java - HTML Unit click on button

Tags: java, htmlunit

I need to click from Java program using HTML Unit, on button from code below:

```
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <div id="Change" class="test-frame">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="r">
                    <div class="c">
                        <div class="c2">
                            <div class="test-window-content">
                                <div class="buttonRow">
                                    <button name="save" type="button" onclick="disableButtons();doChangeCenter('/MakeChangesTestAction');" class="formButton">
    Lock &amp; Edit
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have used below code but returned null pointer exception:

```
HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("http://test");
HtmlForm form2 = page2.getForms().get(0);
HtmlElement htmlElement = (HtmlElement) page2.getElementById("Change");
System.out.println(htmlElement.asXml());
```

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot see a form in side the html code and what is the page attribute of 'page.getForms().get(0);'

Comment: What can I do to manipulate without form name, and above click on this button?

Comment: I think null point exception happen in this line 'HtmlForm form2 = page2.getForms().get(0);' because html don't have form tag try with comment this line